# how to create a month name as a column for a date range for previous month to next 5 months dynamically in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to create a month name as a column for a date range for previous month to next 5 months dynamically in sql server.

I want retrive 6 months data (previous month to next 5 months i.e August 2018 to Jan 2019) based on current month.
suppose if I run same query  next  octomber month that time  6 months data should be   sept 2018 to feb 2019 and months names should be consider as column
names dynamicaly.

table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empproj](
    [projectname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [empname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [startdate] [date] NULL,
    [enddate] [date] NULL,
    [projectstatus] [numeric](18, 2) NULL
) 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empproj] ([projectname], [empname], [startdate], [enddate], [projectstatus]) VALUES (N'p1', N'e1', CAST(N'2018-04-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-12-31' AS Date), CAST(1.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)))
go
INSERT [dbo].[empproj] ([projectname], [empname], [startdate], [enddate], [projectstatus]) VALUES (N'p1', N'e5', CAST(N'2014-02-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-01-31' AS Date), CAST(0.25 AS Numeric(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empproj] ([projectname], [empname], [startdate], [enddate], [projectstatus]) VALUES (N'p2', N'e1', CAST(N'2017-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-03-30' AS Date), CAST(0.75 AS Numeric(18, 2)))
GO
```

based on the above data I want output like below  as per current month run the query.

```
projectname |empname | August2018| September2018|October2018|November2018| December2018|January2019 
p1      |e1      |   1.0     |  1.0         |  1.0      |  1.0       | 1.0          |0.0
p1      |e5      |   0.25    |  0.25        | 0.25      | 0.25       |0.25          |0.25
p2      |e1      |   0.75    |  0.75        | 0.75      |0.75        | 0.75         |0.75
```

if run same query in the next month (october) then result should come like below.

```
projectname |empname |  September2018|October2018|November2018| December2018|January2019 |February2019  
p1      |e1      |   1.0         |  1.0      |  1.0       | 1.0          |0.0        |0.0
p1      |e5      |   0.25        | 0.25      | 0.25       |0.25          |0.25       |0.0
p2      |e1      |   0.75        | 0.75      |0.75        | 0.75         |0.75       |0.75
```

I tried like below :

```
declare @start DATE = (select  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0))

declare @end DATE = (select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+4, 0))

;with months (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,date)<=@end
)

select Datename(month,date)months from months
```

I have got stuck with logic.

How can I write a query to achieve this task month names dynamic column for 6 months data in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE #temp(
    [months] varchar NULL,
)

declare @i int
set @i=-1
while(@i<5)
begin
    insert into #temp values (Datename(month,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+@i, 0)))
    set @i=@i+1
end

select * from #temp